# PyCharm import tensorflow has error but python console works

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm 5.0.5  and  Python3.6 installed by Anaconda.

the Project Interpreter in Pycharm has been correct set to python3.6

Run "import tensoflow" in python console is ok. but when I try to import in PyCharm, it throws error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:/myself/test/test.py", line 14, in <module>
import tensorflow as tf
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import *
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3088, in <module>
@_call_aside
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3072, in _call_aside
f(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3101, in _initialize_master_working_set
working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 565, in _build_master
ws = cls()
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 558, in __init__
self.add_entry(entry)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 614, in add_entry
for dist in find_distributions(entry, True):
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1964, in find_on_path
for dist in factory(fullpath):
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2034, in distributions_from_metadata
root, entry, metadata, precedence=DEVELOP_DIST,
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2473, in from_location
py_version=py_version, platform=platform, **kw
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2835, in _reload_version
md_version = _version_from_file(self._get_metadata(self.PKG_INFO))
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2437, in _version_from_file
line = next(iter(version_lines), '')
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2626, in _get_metadata
if self.has_metadata(name):
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1790, in has_metadata
return name == 'PKG-INFO' and os.path.isfile(self.path)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\genericpath.py", line 33, in isfile
return stat.S_ISREG(st.st_mode)

AttributeError: module 'stat' has no attribute 'S_ISREG'
```

It's confusing that this problem didn't occur before util yesterday.
I can't search any help. How to solve it?

Comment: I can't comment because I don't have the reputation (otherwise I would instead of this answer because it is more of a hint than an answer). But I would guess that it is a dependency issue. I would update all of the packages you are using.

Comment: What are your imports?

Comment: I import only tensorflow  and  tensorflow version is 1.4.0